# Swing control garbled with Chinese, but not with Russian

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, encoding

I work with Eclipse & Java.

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding") == "GBK".
```

All my Swing UI Labels stored in separate properties files(like `messages_ru.properties`,`messages_sc.properties`).

I use native2ascii to convert properties files to get the Unicode.

But one strange thing comes, the label show the Russian correctly,but not correct with the Simple Chinese.  My OS supports Simple Chinese.

Anyone has the same question or has some suggestions to find the Reason? If you need more information, I can show you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `Anyone has the same question or has some suggestions to find the Reason? If you need more information, I can show you.` - agree post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded unicode value stored in local variables instead of properties file

Comment: Another found,when debug it, I use static variables to store the Simple Chinese Text.At debug mode,it shows correct,but when I system.out.print the static variables,it become garbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... Find the reason,it is cause by the Font, My app is using the Factory Font("Calibri") which is not support for Simple Chinese.